# Unable to convert string to date time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I am trying the below piece of code and though the format seems to be correct, it seems to throw an error:

```
from datetime import datetime

utc_time1 = datetime.strptime("2019-07-12T05:49:55:2771249Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%fZ")
print(utc_time1)

utc_time2 = datetime.strptime("2019-07-12T05:49:55.2771249Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")
print(utc_time2)
```

I get the below error :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:/Users/bhatak/PycharmProjects/untitled/test.py", line 3, in <module>
>     utc_time1 = datetime.strptime("2019-07-12T05:49:55:2771249Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%fZ")
>   File "C:\Users\bhatak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
>     tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
>   File "C:\Users\bhatak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\_strptime.py", line 359, in _strptime
>     (data_string, format))
> ValueError: time data '2019-07-12T05:49:55:2771249Z' does not match format '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S:%fZ'
> ```

Comment: `%f` is for microseconds and yet the strings have 7 tailing digits

Comment: [This answer should solve your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: What should be used in this case instead of %f ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

> When used with the strptime() method, the %f directive accepts from
>   one to six digits and zero pads on the right. %f is an extension to
>   the set of format characters in the C standard (but implemented
>   separately in datetime objects, and therefore always available).

Your miliseconds have 7 digits, %f expression can have 6 at maximum. If you delete last one you will not have any problem.

277124 instead of 2771249.